# Property 'x' is declared but never used. False positives

Tags: typescript, tslint

I seem to be getting lots of false positives in my Ionic 3 project:

Is this normal?

12:27:29]  tslint: src/pages/tabs/tabs.ts, line: 28
            Property 'navParams' is declared but never used.

```
  L27:  constructor(
  L28:    private navParams: NavParams,
  L29:    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AuthService ))
```

[12:27:29]  tslint: src/pages/tabs/tabs.ts, line: 30
            Property 'authService' is declared but never used.

```
  L29:    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AuthService ))
  L30:    private authService:AuthService
  L31:  ) {
```

Yet here's the code:

```
export class TabsPage {
  ...
  mySelectedIndex: number;
  loggedIn:boolean;
  constructor(
    private navParams: NavParams,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AuthService ))
    private authService:AuthService
  ) {
    console.log('TabsPage constructor: navParams.data: ', navParams.data);
    this.loggedIn = authService.authenticated(RootPage.LAUNCHPAD.toString());
    this.mySelectedIndex = navParams.data.tabIndex || 0;
    console.log('Tabs pages: selectedIndex: ' + this.mySelectedIndex);
    console.log('Tabs pages: loggedIn: ' + this.loggedIn);
  }

  isLoggedIn():boolean {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the declared variable outside the typescript file then you need to remove the modifier. Try removing private. That will fix this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Since you declare the parameter with a private modifier it will become a class field, and indeed that class field is never used. Remove the modifier if you will only use the parameter in the constructor.

Comment: The short answer would be yes... If you used this then it would count as a property access and it would be used. But if you are going to only use it in your constructor it would be better to not take them class properties.

Comment: yes just remove the `private` modifier or use `this.navParams ` and it will solve the issue and you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It really is a bug in `tslint` as far as I can tell at the moment.  I say this since because I have had similar examples recently where the constructor-injected private member was used in other methods.  So, the field was definitely being used -- just not in the constructor.

At least in my case, I was able to resolve the `tslint` warning by marking those injected parameters as `public`.  Doing this prevents the linter from determining if they are ever referenced.  It's a hack, but at least it gets rid of the warning messages without having to litter your code with `//tslint:disable-next-line` comments before each such constructor.